# as i inspect these are the same codes as my tutor used but result is different tried to figure it out for a while but couldnt help myself out

Tags: php

This is the tutor's screen

[image: this ones tutor's screen]

and this is his code (sorry cant share his original codes but one that i did in the following sentence):

[image: this is his code]

this one is mine -pics aren't the same- but couldn't change size of pics maybe that's where's my mistake is:

[image: this one is mine -pics aren't the same- but couldn't change size of pics maybe that's where's my mistake is]

here is my code that i copy from tutor's screen

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function yaz($resim, $sekil, $x, $y, $golge)
{
    $sz  = getimagesize($sekil);
    $res = getimagesize($resim);
    
    echo $res[0] . '-' . $res[1] . '<br>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $res[0]; $i += $sz[0]) {
        $sol = $x + $i;
        $y1  = $y - $sz[1];
        $y2  = $y + $res[1] + 30;
        echo "<b style='position:absolute;top:$y1;left:$sol;'><img src='$sekil'></b>";
        echo "<b style='position:absolute;top:$y2;left:$sol;'><img src='$sekil'></b>";
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $res[1]; $i += $sz[1]) {
        $ust = $y + $i;
        $x1  = $x - $sz[1];
        $x2  = $x + $res[1] + 30;
        echo "<b style='position:absolute;top:$ust;left:$x1'><img src='$sekil'></b>";
        echo "<b style='position:absolute;top:$ust;left:$x2'><img src='$sekil'></b>";
    }
    echo "<img src='$resim' style='position:absolute;top:$y;left:$x;
                                border-radius: 60px;
                                border: 6px dashed yellow;
                                box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px 15px $golge;'>";
}

yaz("armut_k.jpg", "elma.jpg", 230, 350, "gray");
yaz("elma.jpg", "armut_k.jpg", 630, 250, "blue");
?>
```

Comment: What is the result you get and what is the result you want?

Comment: i want the first one to look like the second even though second one doesn't seem perfect but that's what i meant to do. I can't resize both of the images so i want smaller apples as frame and bigger pear as main-pic. Exactly like the first picture that i attached. Thanks for the reply.